# Can chrome extensions work on about:blank tabs?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can chrome extensions work on about:blank tabs?
I am making a list of exploits and just websites and proxies, and I want to know if chrome extensions such as goguardian and securely can see my screen when I am on an about:blank tab
[about:blank example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNmkw.png)

I have tried searching the web, and read chrome forms themselves, but answers are unclear and mixed.

about blank code:

```
function AB() {
  let inFrame

  try {
    inFrame = window !== top
  } catch (e) {
    inFrame = true
  }

  if (!inFrame && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Firefox')) {
    const popup = open('about:blank', '_blank')
    if (!popup || popup.closed) {
      alert('Please allow popups and redirects.')
    } else {
      const doc = popup.document
      const iframe = doc.createElement('iframe')
      const style = iframe.style
      const link = doc.createElement('link')
      const name = localStorage.getItem('name') || 'My Drive - Google Drive'
      const icon = localStorage.getItem('icon') || 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/drive_2022q3_32dp.png'
      doc.title = name
      link.rel = 'icon'
      link.href = icon
      iframe.src = location.href
      style.position = 'fixed'
      style.top = style.bottom = style.left = style.right = 0
      style.border = style.outline = 'none'
      style.width = style.height = '100%'
      doc.head.appendChild(link)
      doc.body.appendChild(iframe)
      location.replace('https://classroom.google.com')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how that tab is created. If it's opened using `window.open` by a site for which the extension has host permissions then it'll be able to access it.

Comment: @wOxxOm [This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hankypoo7/galaxyabc/main/jsquestion.js?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACOD7LWMJ5RH674OV7LRF2LIZO7RDHA) is my code for the about blanker. It does not use the `window.open` attribute. And im a little bit of a skid so i appriciate you helping me

Comment: Your code uses `open` which is the same as `window.open`, so my comment applies.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh so if i have a website like `example.com`, then if I give the extension access to `example.com` it can see the about:blank tab that was opened on `example.com`? How would I check what extensions have access to `example.com`

Comment: Click the extensions menu icon in the toolbar to the left of the sidebar icon, it'll list extensions sorted by access to the current site.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, when i click on the menu on the about blank tab, it says that goguardian requested access, does that mean that it can only see the about:blank tab when i click the extension to give it access?

Comment: It's a bug, this menu doesn't support such tabs. It works correctly when the original tab is active, and like I said having access to the original tab is sufficient to access this one. Note that depending on how those extensions in question are written they may have problems accessing such tabs.